# Python threading.Thread, scopes and garbage collection

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection, destructor

Say I derive from threading.Thread:

```
from threading import Thread

class Worker(Thread):
    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        Thread.start(self)

    def terminate(self):
        self.running = False
        self.join()

    def run(self):
        import time
        while self.running:
            print "running"
            time.sleep(1)
```

Any instance of this class with the thread being started must have it's thread actively terminated before it can get garbage collected (the thread holds a reference itself). So this is a problem, because it completely defies the purpose of garbage collection. In that case having some object encapsulating a thread, and with the last instance of the object *going out of scope* the destructor gets called for thread termination and cleanup. Thuss a destructor

```
    def __del__(self):
        self.terminate()
```

will not do the trick.

The only way I see to nicely encapsulate threads is by using low level `thread` builtin module and `weakref` weak references. Or I may be missing something fundamental. So is there a nicer way than tangling things up in `weakref` spaghetti code?

Comment: So the problem is that each time the destructor gets called, it terminates your thread? But you only want to terminate it on the *last* de-reference, yes? Can't you just solve that with your own reference count?

Comment: No, the problem is, that the destructor will not be called at all. The Python GC sees there's still a reference hold against the instance (by the thread), so it will not delete it, hence no destruction takes place which would shut down the thread. Basically I'd like to terminate the thread when the last instance of Worker goes out of scope, i.e. the GC should ignore references held by the thread. This is what a weakref would to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a wrapper class (which has-a `Thread` rather than is-a `Thread`)?

eg:

```
class WorkerWrapper:
    __init__(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
    __del__(self):
        self.worker.terminate()
```

And then use these wrapper classes in client code, rather than threads directly.

Or perhaps I miss something (:

Comment: Hmm, that might work. Though I don't like the idea of wrappers. I try to avoid onion-programming if possible, and the project I'm working on already has enough wrappers as it is. But if this works out I may actually use it.

Comment: Although I didn't follow your suggestion, it brought me on the right track: The worker now instantiates a Thread in the following way: `self.worker_thread = Thread(target = WorkerClass.worker_function, args = (weakref(self),))` That allows WorkerClass instances to get out of scope and garbage collected, which allows to gracefully stop the thread by setting a flag and join() it in the destructor.

Comment: Can you post your complete solution as another answer to this question? I'm having a hard time visualizing what you've done based on your short answer here.

Answer (score 2):

To add an answer inspired by @datenwolf's comment, here is another way to do it that deals with the object being deleted or the parent thread ending:

```
import threading
import time
import weakref

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_thread = threading.current_thread()

        self.initialised = threading.Event()
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=Foo.threaded_func,
                args=(weakref.proxy(self), ))

        self.t.start()
        while not self.initialised.is_set():
            # This loop is necessary to stop the main threading doing anything
            # until the exception handler in threaded_func can deal with the 
            # object being deleted.
            pass

    def __del__(self):
        print 'self:', self, self.main_thread.is_alive()
        self.t.join()

    def threaded_func(self):

        self.initialised.set()

        try:
            while True:
                print time.time()

                if not self.main_thread.is_alive():
                    print('Main thread ended')
                    break

                time.sleep(1)

        except ReferenceError:
            print('Foo object deleted')

foo = Foo()
del foo
foo = Foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are a convert from C++ where a lot of meaning can be attached to scopes of variables, equalling lifetimes of variables. This is not the case for Python, and garbage collected languages in general.
*Scope != Lifetime* simply because garbage collection occurs whenever the interpreter gets around to it, not on scope boundaries. Especially as you are trying to do asynchronuous stuff with it, the raised hairs on your neck should vibrate to the clamour of all the warning bells in your head!
You can do stuff with the lifetime of objects, using '**del**'.
(In fact, if you read the sources to the cpython garbage collector module, the obvious (and somewhat funny) disdain for objects with finalizers (**del** methods) expressed there, should tell everybody to use even the lifetime of an object only if necessary).

You could use sys.getrefcount(self) to find out when to leave the loop in your thread. But I can hardly recommend that (just try out what numbers it returns. You won't be happy. To see who holds what just check gc.get_referrers(self)).
The reference count may/will depend on garbage collection as well.

Besides, tying the runtime of a thread of execution to scopes/lifetimes of objects is an error 99% of the time. Not even Boost does it. It goes out of its RAII way to define something called a 'detached' thread.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

Comment: Damn, just noticed the date on the op. .. Oh well.

Comment: You somehow misunderstood the my problem. My problem was actually not really the *scope* of the Thread object, but that the thread encapsulated by this object will claim a reference to the Thread instance too. This creates a dependency cycle that prevents the object from being garbage collected up that prevents the thread from terminating that prevents the object from being garbage collected… So my question was about how I could effectively detach the thread from the Thread object instance (see Boost detached thread) so that garbage collection on the managing Thread object can work at all.

Comment: The solution was like what jwd suggested, I just varied it a bit. A practical example would be a file like object that has to perform a continously running background task to keep the object open (for example say a bit banged connection to a debugging circuit that wants to see a watchdog bit toggle every 10ms). My problem then was very similar. Anyway, without the Thread instance getting garbage collected the process will not terminate and must be killed, which of course prevents any cleanup routines of the process to run.

Comment: Thx for the interest taken. I think I got it mostly right, but made a philosophical argument (Thread instances terminating on gc/scope is bad) to a practical problem (running thread is immortal). Your solution sounds sound, as it does not terminate the thread on death of the wrapper, it signals it to get its things in order and then commit suicide, and only that signal is tied to the lifetime of an object. Since all is well, a happy farewell to you.