# Python threading. Class won't get deleted if it owns a running thread

Tags: python, multithreading, class, garbage-collection, scopes

I'm trying to create a python-package for calling non-blocking commands. What i came up with is a simple "Executer"-class which will have a thread and a queue with commands to execute one after the other. While the excuting of the commands seem to work, the programm never quits, as the executer-class never gets deleted by the garbage collector, after the object runs out of scope.

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import weakref

class Commands:
    """Class for all Commands"""
    Command: str = ""
    IsDone: bool = False
    WasSuccessfull: bool = False
    Value: object = None

    def __init__(self, InputCommand):
        self.Command = InputCommand

    def GetValue(self) -> object:
        while not self.IsDone:
            time.sleep(0.01)

        return self.Value

    def WaitForFinished(self):
        while not self.IsDone:
            time.sleep(0.01)



class Executer:       
    CommandQueue: queue.Queue = queue.Queue()
    Worker: threading.Thread = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.Worker = threading.Thread(target=weakref.proxy(Executer.__WorkerThread__), args=(weakref.proxy(self) ,))
        self.Worker.start()


    def __del__(self):
        print("Exiting")
        self.AddCommand("__STOP__")
        self.Worker.join()


    def AddCommand(self, CommandText) -> Commands:
        Command = Commands(CommandText)
        self.CommandQueue.put(Command)
        return Command

    def __WorkerThread__ (self):
        while True:
            if self.CommandQueue.empty():
                time.sleep(0.01)
            else:
                Command = self.CommandQueue.get()
                print(Command.Command)
                # Emulate some work
                time.sleep(0.5)
                Command.IsDone = True
                Command.WasSuccessfull = True
                if(Command.Command == "__STOP__"):
                    break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exe = Executer()
    Command = exe.AddCommand("Yeah 0")
    exe.AddCommand("Yeah 1")
    exe.AddCommand("Yeah 2")
    exe.AddCommand("Yeah 3")
    exe.AddCommand("Yeah 4")
    x = Command.GetValue()
    print(x)
    print("Done")
```

It seems to be the same problem as mentioned here:
[Python threading.Thread, scopes and garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359469/python-threading-thread-scopes-and-garbage-collection)

While the solution (in his comments) seem to work for the author, it doesn't work for me after integrating it. The main-thread will run trough and all my Commands will get executed but the subthread won't die as the "executer"-class doesn't gets deleted.

The class would get deleted if the user specifically called `del exe`, but this is not a nice python approach, as the user of my package would always need to clean up the class by themself.

Comment: Relying on calling of `__del__` and garbage collection isn't a good idea as it can happen any time later. Better would be a more complex approach where the worker thread terminates when there isn't anything more to do and a new one is started as needed. This would need the use of thread synchronization primitives to ensure that not two threads are running at once or none although there is work to do.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the response. This worked pretty well, but has still the downside that the programm either creates a massive amount of threads (if badly timed) or has a threshold time which needs to run out a the end of the programm. 
A hybrid version with threshold time and the executer class which gets destroyed after it runs out of context would be awesome.
But i still can't find the reason why it won't get destroyed.

Comment: The reason is that the "exe" global variable still references the Executer object. As long as it is reachable it won't be garbage collected, therefore the thread is not terminated and as long as one non-daemon thread is alive the program won't terminate. Another possible solution would be to pack the main code in a function (with "exe" as local variable) which would make Executer unreachable on return. But this may not be suitable for your real use-case.